# Avoid repeating using the filter function

Tags: google-sheets

I was creating an accounting log, so right now I'm using:

```
   =SUM(FILTER(Transactions!C:C,Transactions!B:B>=D23,Transactions!B:B<=E23,Transactions!E:E="Summary!C65"),FILTER(Transactions!C:C,Transactions!B:B>=D23,Transactions!B:B<=E23,Transactions!E:E=Summary!C66),FILTER(Transactions!C:C,Transactions!B:B>=D23,Transactions!B:B<=E23,Transactions!E:E=Summary!C67),FILTER(Transactions!C:C,Transactions!B:B>=D23,Transactions!B:B<=E23,Transactions!E:E=Summary!C68))
```

The first two criteria in the filter function check if the range is within a specific date range, and the final criterion checks if the type of transaction is relevant. But it's not letting me compare multiple values so I have to keep repeating the filter function.

Posting the same formula for more clarity

```
=SUM(FILTER(Transactions!C:C,Transactions!B:B>=D23,Transactions!B:B<=E23,Transactions!E:E="Nuts"),FILTER(Transactions!C:C,Transactions!B:B>=D23,Transactions!B:B<=E23,Transactions!E:E="Bolts"),FILTER(Transactions!C:C,Transactions!B:B>=D23,Transactions!B:B<=E23,Transactions!E:E="Screws"),FILTER(Transactions!C:C,Transactions!B:B>=D23,Transactions!B:B<=E23,Transactions!E:E="Clips"))
```

Is there a way for me to just compare if the transaction done is "Nuts, Bolts, Screws or Clips" in one go without having to repeat the filter function?

Answer (score 1):

Can't test if it will work without a sample spreadsheet, but try

```
   =SUM(FILTER(
     Transactions!C:C,
     Transactions!B:B>=D23,
     Transactions!B:B<=E23,
     MATCH(Transactions!E:E, Summary!C65:C68, 0)
    ))
```